# Javascript Constructor of new Object([]) / new Object(new Array())

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

### Regarding : new Object(new Array())

there's a quite rather fundamental question that me myself really could not come up with an answer to, which i am seeking advice for:
When instantiating an object in js using the following method:
`var obj = new Object();`
It's obvious: **`obj.constructor === Object`** , 

**however**,
 when doing something slightly different such as instantiating an object of type Array:

```
var obj = new Object([]);
```

becomes
**`obj.constructor === Array`**

What exactly is happening here?
 I fully get why in the first example obj.constructor === Object 
but why is the constructor of obj Array when the Array was created via new Object?

Wouldn't the constructor of obj on first roll have to be Object.constructor?
As
 var obj = new Object([]); is the same as  var obj = new Object(new Array());

- Would this mean the constructor returned by a new Object that was
  itself creating a new Object of another type, would always the the
  latest/newest assigned in that "chain"?
- Or does object simply inherit the constructor from it's first
  parameter (of specific type)?

**Cheerio**

Comment: Object isn't really designed to take params.

Comment: @dandavis: Well, it converts the argument to an object, just like e.g. `Number` converts the argument to a number.

Comment: @FelixKling: yeah, but how useful is that in a land of provided objects like xhr/dom method returns and literals? It does work, it's just not too useful. It can be a good "allow all" [].filter() argument, and Object.keys() needs a home somewhere, but calling it; why bother...

Comment: @dandavis: I agree, it doesn't seem to be very useful. But I wouldn't say that it is "not designed" to take arguments :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets have a look at the specification:

> [**15.2.2.1 new Object ( [ value ] )**](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.2.1)
> When the `Object` constructor is called with no arguments or with one argument value, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If *value* is supplied, then
>    a. If Type(*value*) is Object, then
>       i. If the value is a native ECMAScript object, do not create a new object but simply return *value*.

That means, if you pass an object to `Object`, it simply returns the very same value. So `var obj = new Object([]);` is really the same as `var obj = [];`, and we can easily test that:

```
> var arr = []; // or var arr = new Array();
> var obj = new Object(arr);
> arr === obj;
true
```

If you pass an argument that is not an object, it will be converted to an object, e.g.

```
> typeof new Object("string")
'object'
```

If you don't supply any argument, it simply returns a new object:

```
> new Object()
Object {}
```

Also note that as per specification, `Object(...)` behaves exactly like `new Object(...)`.